# POST http://localhost:8000/comment/saveComment 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, mern

New to react here. I am using a mern stack with express mongoose and node js. I am trying to create a comment functionality for a youtube clone, and I have been following a youtube video but for some reason I can't get it to work. I do not know if the routes are the problem, if it's the post axios method or the models.
Here is the post.js

```
import { Avatar, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";
import SmsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Sms";
import SpaIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Spa";
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import minime from "../images/me.jpg";
import vid from "../videos/ed.MP4";
import GpsFixedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/GpsFixed";
import FormatListBulletedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FormatListBulleted";
import GamepadIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Gamepad";
import "../styles/Post.css";
import EmojiEmotionsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/EmojiEmotions";
import VideoModal from "./VideoModal";
import PostMotivationModal from "../components/modals/PostMotivationModal";
import PostHappinessModal from "../components/modals/PostHappinessModal";
import Comments from "./post/Comments";
import axios from "../axios";

const Post = ({
  avatar,
  name,
  caption,
  filePath,
  motivation,
  goals,
  happiness,
}) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [motivationIsOpen, setMotivationIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [happinessIsOpen, setHappinessIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const vidRef = useRef(null);
  const [commentList, setCommentList] = useState([]);

  const handleVideoPress = () => {
    //If video is playing... stop it
    if (playing) {
      vidRef.current.pause();
      setPlaying(false);
    } else {
      vidRef.current.play();
      setPlaying(true);
    }

    //otherwise... play it
  };
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
  const [vid, setVid] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchPosts() {
      const res = await axios.get("video/getVideos");
      setVideos(res.data.videos);
      let video = res.data.videos.find((video) => video._id);
      console.log(video);
      setVid(video);

      return res;
    }
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   async function fetchPosts() {
  //     const res = await axios.get("video/getVideo");
  //     setVid(res.data.video);
  //     let video = res.data.videos.find((video) => video._id);
  //     console.log(video);
  //     setVid(video);

  //     return res;
  //   }
  //   fetchPosts();
  // }, []);

  const videoId = vid._id;

  const variable = {
    videoId: videoId,
  };

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   axios.post("/video/getVideo", variable).then((response) => {
  //     console.log(response.data);
  //     if (response.data.success) {
  //       setVid(response.data.video);
  //     } else {
  //       console.log(response.data);
  //       alert("Failed to get video Info");
  //     }
  //   });
  // }, []);

  const updateComment = (newComment) => {
    setCommentList(commentList.push(newComment));
  };

  return (
    <div className="post">
      <div className="post-head">
        <div className="post-header">
          <Avatar src={avatar} />
          <h3>{name}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="caption">
          <p>{caption}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="video-container">
        <div className="flex-container">
          <div className="video-card">
            <video
              ratiowidth="calc(0.56 * (400px + (100vw - 768px) / 1152 * 100))"
              ratioheight="calc(400px + (100vw - 768px) / 1152 * 100)"
              musicinfomaxwidth="250.56"
              style={{
                width: "calc(0.56 * (400px + ((100vw - 768px) / 1152) * 100))",
              }}
              loop
              onClick={handleVideoPress}
              ref={vidRef}
              src={`http://localhost:8000/${filePath}`}
            ></video>
            <div className="post__personalItems">
              <div title="Goals" className="personalIcon">
                <GpsFixedIcon
                  onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                />
              </div>

              <div title="Motivation" className="personalIcon">
                <GamepadIcon
                  onClick={() => setMotivationIsOpen(true)}
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                />
              </div>
              <div title="Happiness" className="personalIcon">
                <EmojiEmotionsIcon
                  onClick={() => setHappinessIsOpen(true)}
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <VideoModal
              open={isOpen}
              onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
              goals={goals}
            ></VideoModal>

            <PostMotivationModal
              open={motivationIsOpen}
              onClose={() => setMotivationIsOpen(false)}
              motivation={motivation}
            ></PostMotivationModal>

            <PostHappinessModal
              open={happinessIsOpen}
              onClose={() => setHappinessIsOpen(false)}
              happiness={happiness}
            ></PostHappinessModal>
          </div>

          <div className="post-icons">
            <div className="post-icon" title="like">
              <IconButton>
                <FavoriteIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <div className="icon-detail">
                <p>112</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="post-icon" title="hug">
              <IconButton>
                <SpaIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <div className="icon-detail">
                <p>300</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="post-icon" title="comment">
              <IconButton>
                <SmsIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <div className="icon-detail">
                <p>30</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <Comments
        commentList={commentList}
        postId={videoId}
        refreshFunction={updateComment}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

here is the comment.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Input } from "antd";
import "../../styles/Comments.css";
import axios from "../../axios";
const { TextArea } = Input;

const Comments = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile")));
  const [submitOn, setSubmitOn] = useState(false);
  const [comment, setComment] = useState("");
  const btnSwap = () => {
    if (submitOn === false) {
      setSubmitOn(true);
    }
  };
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setComment(e.currentTarget.value);
  };
  //   console.log(user?.result.googleId);
  //   console.log(props);
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const variables = {
      content: comment,
      name: user?.result.name,
      avatar: user?.result.imageUrl,
      postId: props.postId,
    };

    axios.post("/comment/saveComment", variables).then((res) => {
      if (res.data.success) {
        setComment("");
        props.refreshFunction(res.data.result);
      } else {
        alert("Failed to save comment");
      }
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="comments-section">
      <p className="replies-txt">Replies</p>

      <hr />
      {/*Comment Lists */}
      {console.log(props.commentList)}
      {/* Root comment form */}
      <form className="comment-form1" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input
          className="txtarea-comments"
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={comment}
          placeholder="Type your comments here..."
          onClick={btnSwap}
        />
        <div className="comment-submit-div">
          <button
            className={submitOn ? "txt-true" : "comment-submit-btn"}
            onClick={onSubmit}
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Comments;
```

here is the models/comment.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const commentSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    avatar: { type: String },
    postId: { type: String },
    responseTo: { type: String },
    content: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

here is the comment router

```
import express from "express";
import Comment from "../models/Comment.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/saveComment", (req, res) => {
  const comment = new Comment(req.body);

  comment.save((err, comment) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, err });
    Comment.find({ _id: comment._id })
      .populate("name", "avatar")
      .exec((err, result) => {
        if (err) return res.json({ success: false, err });
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, result });
      });
  });
});

export default router;
```

here is the videos router

```
import express from "express";
import multer from "multer";
import Upload from "../models/Upload.js";

const router = express.Router();

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, `${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`);
  },
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    if (ext !== ".mp4") {
      return cb(res.status(400).end("only video format is allowed"), false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
  },
});

let upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("file");

//=================================
//             Video
//=================================

router.post("/uploadfiles", (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.json({ success: false, err });
    }
    return res.json({
      success: true,
      filePath: res.req.file.path,
      fileName: res.req.file.filename,
    });
  });
});

router.post("/uploadVideo", (req, res) => {
  const video = new Upload(req.body);

  video.save((err, video) => {
    if (err) return res.status(400).json({ success: false, err });
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
    });
  });
});

router.get("/getVideos", (req, res) => {
  Upload.find()
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .exec((err, videos) => {
      if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, videos });
    });
});

router.post("/getVideo", (req, res) => {
  Upload.findOne({ _id: req.body.videoId })
    .populate("name", "avatar")
    .exec((err, video) => {
      if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, video });
    });
});

export default router;
```

here is the server.js

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import data from "./data.js";
import Videos from "./dbModel.js";
import postRoutes from "./routes/posts.js";
import userRouter from "./routes/user.js";
import commentRouter from "./routes/comment.js";

import uploadRouter from "./routes/upload.js";

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

//Middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use("/posts", postRoutes);
app.use("/user", userRouter);

app.use("/video", uploadRouter);

app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  // index.html for all page routes
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.use("/comment", commentRouter);

//db config
const CONNECTION_URL =
  "mongodb+srv://dimerson:9zRHuVcHLh5fSznu@cluster0.5n5rb.mongodb.net/KweebleDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.status(200).send("hello world"));

app.get("/v1/posts", (req, res) => res.status(200).send(data));
app.post("/v2/posts", (req, res) => {
  const dbVideos = req.body;
  Videos.create(dbVideos, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.status(201).send(data);
    }
  });
});

app.get("/v2/posts", (req, res) => {
  Videos.find((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(data);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on localhost:${port}`));
```